# Create multiple varaibles when using reshape/cast r

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I'm working with survey data and have some cases when the respondent has answered the survey multiple times and therefore exists in multiple rows in the data. Like this:

```
Id Question1
1     5
1     3
2     3
3     5
4     1
```

I would like to cast/reshape the data to a wide format where I can get  it like this:

```
Id Question1 Question1.v2
1     5          3
2     3        missing  
3     5        missing
4     1        missing
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
df = read.table(text = "
Id Question1
1     5
1     3
2     3
3     5
4     1
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(row = paste0("Question1.v", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(row, Question1)

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      Id Question1.v1 Question1.v2
# * <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1     1            5            3
# 2     2            3           NA
# 3     3            5           NA
# 4     4            1           NA
```

I'd suggest you don't use `missing`, but `NA` instead so you can still treat your variable as numeric.

If you want an exact match of your output for any reason try this instead:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(row = paste0("Question1.v", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(row, Question1) %>%
  rename(Question1 = Question1.v1) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "missing", x))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      Id Question1 Question1.v2
#   <int>     <int>        <chr>
# 1     1         5            3
# 2     2         3      missing
# 3     3         5      missing
# 4     4         1      missing
```

Comment: 8 sec faster :)

Comment: :-D Keep your answer. You had a slightly alternative approach there using `complete`.

Comment: No need to paste it.......... Save it as a dataframe with a specific name and use that name instead of `df` that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data table package you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(Id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), Question1 = c(5, 3, 3, 5, 1))
```

In your case if you have the dataframe df1 you should do first `setDT(df1)` to turn it into a data table.

```
dat1[, temp := paste0("Question1.V", 1:.N), by = Id]
res <- dcast(dat1, Id ~ temp, value.var = "Question1")
names(res)[2] <- "Question1"

> res
   Id Question1 Question1.V2
1:  1         5            3
2:  2         3           NA
3:  3         5           NA
4:  4         1           NA
```